# Does 'compile ...' in gradle requieres internet in the installation device?

Tags: android, gradle, compilation

I'm working on a project and using the Google GSM Vision library to read a QR Code by adding

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0'
```

in my app gradle.

After doing it, the project syncs and now I'm able to use the lib and I can launch the app in my own device.

The problem is. What happens if the target does not have access to internet and it does not have a Google account? Will it run or the lib needs to be downloaded after or during the installation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation of APK, mobile vision api bundled with APK. So, internet is not required and google account is not necessary.

From Doc :

> Note: ProGuard directives are included in the Play services client
>   libraries to preserve the required classes. The Android Plugin for
>   Gradle automatically appends ProGuard configuration files in an AAR
>   (Android ARchive) package and appends that package to your ProGuard
>   configuration. During project creation, Android Studio automatically
>   creates the ProGuard configuration files and build.gradle properties
>   for ProGuard use. To use ProGuard with Android Studio, you must enable
>   the ProGuard setting in your build.gradle buildTypes. For more
>   information, see the ProGuard guide.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Gradle can try to connect to the web. If you have your dependency downloaded in cache you can build the app in --offline mode.

Comment: But when you have apk created, the internet will not be required to this.